# Memory leak detected by Memory Analyzer in Eclipse

Tags: java, tomcat

Hi does anyone know how to resolve this  "The classloader/component "org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader @ 0x6c0706e30" occupies 5,030,872 (19.46%) bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance of "java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node[]" loaded by "".  Keywords java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Node[] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader @ 0x6c0706e30"

Comment: Classloaders probably do accumulate a large amount of objects, and I'd kinda doubt that a well tested component like Apache has a bug.  I'd suspect your memory analyzer is a little faulty and has jumped the gun.

Comment: Looks like Tomcat to me; are you loading and unloading a web application?

Comment: @markspace Have a look at the Apache bug database and you'll change your mind ;) We just can bet that bugs impacting many people are solved fast, but there are tons of unsolved (whatever the reason, hard to reproduce,..)

Comment: There is probably nothing to solve @user9512425 . We don't know how much memory you gave to your Tomcat, and which version you are using. On a small sized Tomcat (500MB), 100MB of loaded files is already 20%.